# Accessing WoW data from outside

Tags: world-of-warcraft

Is there any way to get API function values from outside wow?. I mean, if I make an addon to read something inside the game,can I have these to manipulate it outside thw wow?

Regards,
Carlos.

Answer (score 0):

No, at least nothing legally in real-time. Addons only have access to the [SavedVariables](https://wow.gamepedia.com/SavedVariables) which are updated on logging out and on /reload

Comment: Ok, so. It's not possible make a keyboard that lighst the keys when the spell are available. isn't it?

Comment: Recalling that a friend spoke about his keyboard changes colors depending on the Overwatch hero he's playing, I googled and found this: http://www.project-aurora.com/ But it makes no mention of WoW.